# How do I solve differential equation $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=(2x(t)+8)(t^4+2t^2-t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=(2x+8)(t^4+2t^2-t)$?

$\frac{dx}{2x(t)+8}=dt(t^4+2t^2-t)$

$\frac{1}{2}\ln(2x+8)=\frac{t^5}{5}+2\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2}$

$e^{\ln(2x+8)}=e^{2(\frac{t^5}{5}+2\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2})}$

$2x+8=e^{2(\frac{t^5}{5}+2\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2})}$

$2x=e^{2(\frac{t^5}{5}+2\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2})}-8$

$x=\frac{e}{2}^{2(\frac{t^5}{5}+2\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2})}-4$

$x(0)=3$

Is the above calculation correct?

I can put that values, so I get:

$\frac{1}{2}\ln(14)=-C$

Where do I write value of the constant C in the solution $x(t)$?

Comment: Okay I corrected my mistake. @Moo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2}\ln(2x+8)=\frac{t^5}{5}+2\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2}+C$

I advocate waiting until the end to solve for $C.$  There is a lot of algebra to follow, and it is easier if there is one less thing to think about.

For example,  $C$ is an arbitrary constant.  Multiply by $2, 2C$ is equally arbitrary, so just leave it as $C.$

$\ln(2x+8)=2\frac{t^5}{5}+4\frac{t^3}{3}-{t^2}+C$

$e^{\ln(2x+8)} = e^{(2\frac{t^5}{5}+4\frac{t^3}{3}-{t^2}+C)}\\
2x+8 = e^{(2\frac{t^5}{5}+4\frac{t^3}{3}-{t^2})}e^C\\
2x+8 = Ce^{(2\frac{t^5}{5}+4\frac{t^3}{3}-{t^2})}$

Same game, $e^C$ and $C$ are equally arbitrary constants.

$x+4 = Ce^{(2\frac{t^5}{5}+4\frac{t^3}{3}-{t^2})}\\
x = Ce^{(2\frac{t^5}{5}+4\frac{t^3}{3}-{t^2})}-4$

Now, lets tackle $C$ in the initial condition.
$x(0) = C - 4 = 3$

$x = 7e^{(2\frac{t^5}{5}+4\frac{t^3}{3}-{t^2})}-4$

Comment: I think you have mistake when you from 2x+8 make x+4 you have to devide right side with 2 to. Am I right?

Comment: You missed the point of my lesson.  What does $\frac C2$ equal?

Comment: Haha, I don't know...

Comment: At that step in the calculation $C$ is still an arbitrary constant.  $\frac C2$ is also an arbitrary constant.  So, just keep calling it $C$ unit it is time to assign a value to it.

Comment: Personally I prefer to give $C$ an index at the start and increment it each time I do something that would change it. Then I don't have to keep track of the changes I make to it (recognizing that it's still an arbitrary constant), but I also make it plain to any reader (including myself) that they're not the same constant at each step.


Also, it's good to remember that you have an absolute value within the log function after you integrated, but that ultimately ends up as a +/- combined in $C$.

Comment: @Turambar I can respect that preference.  I guess it comes down to how lazy a person is (I am lazy) and which you find easier to keep track of.